# Christmas tree in Python with decorations

Tags: python

I need to draw a xmas tree in Python with user input height and interval to put decorations balls on a tree but decorations balls should be after one symbol like on a schema below:

```
                X               
                ^               
            /   *   \           
        /   *   1   *   \       
    /   *   2   *   3   *   \   
/   *   4   *   5   *   6   *   \
            |       |
```

If user inputs "5 1" I should have:

```
                X               
                ^               
            /   *   \           
        /   *   O   *   \       
    /   *   O   *   O   *   \   
/   *   O   *   O   *   O   *   \
            |       |
```

If user inputs "5 3":

```
                X               
                ^               
            /   *   \           
        /   *   O   *   \       
    /   *   *   *   *   *   \   
/   *   O   *   *   *   *   *   \
            |       |
```

That was no problem for me to draw a tree without decorations:

```
print(f'{" " * (height - 1)}X')
print(f'{" " * (height - 1)}^')
for i in range(1, height):
    stars = 2 * i - 1
    spaces = height - i - 1
    print(f"{spaces * ' '}/{stars * '*'}\\")
print(f'{" " * (height - 2)}| |')
```

But I dont have any idea how to put decoration balls on it. Do any one have?

Comment: I think you should include printing 'O' somewhere in your code. That's my idea.

Comment: @mkrieger1, oh, thank you! How cant I get it earlier :)

Comment: The input is height and interval. In your example, the input height is 5 and yet your required output is comprised of 7 rows! Also, your code does not produce that output

Comment: @Codist I was asking about how to put decoration not about the height.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To those who will search after me:

```
height, interval = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
positions = [str(ii) for ii in range(1, height * height, interval)]

row = []
n = 1
for i in range(1, height):
    branch = []
    for ii in "*" * (2 * i - 1):
        if len(branch) % 2 == 0:
            branch += ["*"]
        else:
            branch += [str(n)]
            n += 1
    row += [branch]

new_row = []
for branch in row:
    new_branch = []
    for star in branch:
        if star.isdigit() and star in positions:
            new_branch += ["O"]
        else:
            new_branch += ["*"]
    new_row += [new_branch]

print(f'{" " * (height - 1)}X')
print(f'{" " * (height - 1)}^')
for i in range(1, height):
    print(f"{((height - i - 1) * ' ')}/{''.join(new_row[i - 1])}\\")
print(f'{" " * (height - 2)}| |')
```

May be is a long way but it works.

For "14 6":

```
             X
             ^
            /*\
           /*O*\
          /*****\
         /*******\
        /*O*******\        
       /*****O*****\       
      /*******O*****\      
     /*******O*******\     
    /*****O***********\    
   /*O***********O*****\   
  /*******O***********O*\  
 /***********O***********\ 
/*O***********O***********\
            | |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to duplicate your middle section: instead of using only `*`, include also the `o`:

```py
def show_tree(height: int) -> None:
    print(f'{" " * (height - 1)}X')
    print(f'{" " * (height - 1)}^')
    for i in range(1, height):
        stars = 2 * i - 1
        spaces = height - i - 1

        # Instead of `stars * '*'`, intersperse it with `o`
        # by using `stars * '*o'` and trim by the length 
        # you want (in this case, `stars` itself)
        middle = (stars * '*o')[:stars]

        print(f"{spaces * ' '}/{middle}\\")
    print(f'{" " * (height - 2)}| |')

show_tree(10)
```

The above outputs

```
         X
         ^
        /*\
       /*o*\
      /*o*o*\
     /*o*o*o*\
    /*o*o*o*o*\
   /*o*o*o*o*o*\
  /*o*o*o*o*o*o*\
 /*o*o*o*o*o*o*o*\
/*o*o*o*o*o*o*o*o*\
        | |
```

Comment: Thats clear but how can I use interval to put "o" in special places?

Comment: because it is the mst difficult part